# Node/Sequelize: loading all models

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have 4 models in the models folder (artisans, stores, items and itemStores,) but it only loads the items model into the db variable. Why might this be?

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var db = require('./models');
var artisans = require('./app/routes/artisans.js');
var stores = require('./app/routes/stores.js');
var items = require('./app/routes/items.js');
var itemStores = require('./app/routes/itemStores.js');

var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Set up the express app to handle data parsing
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended : true }));
app.use(bodyParser.text());
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type : "application/vmd.api-json"}));

// Static directory
app.use(express.static("app/public"));

artisans(app, db);
stores(app, db);
items(app, db);
itemsStores(app, db);

console.log(Object.keys(db));

db.sequelize.sync().then(function () {
    app.listen(PORT, function () {
        console.log('Listening on PORT ' + PORT);
    });
});
```

./models/index.js

```
'use strict';

var fs        = require('fs');
var path      = require('path');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var basename  = path.basename(__filename);
var env       = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var config    = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
var db        = {};

if (config.use_env_variable) {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], 
config);
} else {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, 
config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && 
(file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    var model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

./models/artisan.js

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var artisan = sequelize.define("Item", {
        name: DataTypes.STRING,
        email: DataTypes.STRING,
        website: DataTypes.STRING,
        phoneNumber: DataTypes.INTEGER
    });

    return artisan;
};
```

./models/item.js

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var item = sequelize.define("Item", {
        name: DataTypes.STRING,
        price: DataTypes.DECIMAL,
        category: DataTypes.STRING,
        artisanId: DataTypes.INTEGER
    });

    return item;
};
```

./models/itemStore.js

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var itemStore = sequelize.define("Item", {
        itemId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        storeId: DataTypes.INTEGER
    });

    return itemStore;
};
```

./models/store.js

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var store = sequelize.define("Item", {
        name: DataTypes.STRING,
        addressLineOne: DataTypes.STRING,
        addressLineTwo: DataTypes.STRING,
        city: DataTypes.STRING,
        state: DataTypes.STRING,
        zip: DataTypes.INTEGER
    });

    return store;
};
```

Another detail I can add is that I did a tutorial to come up with the skeleton for this. the tutorial had only an items model, so this might be an artifact from that.

The output of console.log(db) is too large to submit here, but it returns a json and its keys are [ 'Item', 'sequelize', 'Sequelize' ].

Comment: Show the code in `./models`

Comment: post some more code. Also post the output of `console.log(db)`

Comment: The `sequelize.define()` is a definition of `database tables`, and in your case, they are all named `Item`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Create folder `database/definitions`
2. Put that `index.js` in `models` folder to `database` folder
3. Put Your model definitions (schemas) into `database/definitions` folder
4. Create `database/definitions/index.js` and define such body:

```js
    module.exports.Artisan = require('./Artisan');
    module.exports.Store = require('./Store');
    module.exports.Item = require('./Item');
    module.exports.ItemStore = require('./ItemStore');
```

- make sure definition files are UpperCased - it's for convention

5. Model definitions:

**database/definitions/Artisan.js**

```js
    const DataTypes = require('sequelize');

    module.exports = {
      table: 'artisans',
      fields: {
        name: DataTypes.STRING,
        email: DataTypes.STRING,
        website: DataTypes.STRING,
        phoneNumber: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      }
    };
```

**database/definitions/Store.js**

```js
    const DataTypes = require('sequelize');

    module.exports = {
      table: 'stores',
      fields: {
        name: DataTypes.STRING,
        addressLineOne: DataTypes.STRING,
        addressLineTwo: DataTypes.STRING,
        city: DataTypes.STRING,
        state: DataTypes.STRING,
        zip: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      }
    };
```

**database/definitions/Item.js**

```js
    const DataTypes = require('sequelize');

    module.exports = {
      table: 'items',
      fields: {
        name: DataTypes.STRING,
        price: DataTypes.DECIMAL,
        category: DataTypes.STRING,
        artisanId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      }
    };
```

**database/definitions/ItemStore.js**

```js
    const DataTypes = require('sequelize');

    module.exports = {
      table: 'items_stores',
      fields: {
        itemId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        storeId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      }
    };
```

6. Full code of `database/index.js` :

```js
    const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
    const env       = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
    const config    = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];

    const connection = config.use_env_variable ? 
      new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config) :
      new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);

    const definitions = require('./definitions'); 
    const models = {};
    for(const name in definitions) {
      models[name] = connection.define(
        definitions[name].table,
        definitions[name].fields,
      );
    }

    module.exports = {
      connection, models
    };
```

7. Full code of `server.js` :

```js
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const db = require('./database');
    
    var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
    
    // Set up the express app to handle data parsing
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended : true }));
    app.use(bodyParser.text());
    app.use(bodyParser.json({ type : "application/vmd.api-json"}));
    app.use(express.static("app/public"));
    
    // how to use models:
    app.get('/artisans/:id', async (req, res) => {
      try {
        const { Artisan } = db.models;
        const artisan = await Artisan.findOne(req.params);
        res.status(200).send(artisan);
      }
      catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send(error);
      }
    });


    db.connection.sync().then(() => {
      app.listen(PORT, () => console.log('Listening on PORT:', PORT));
    });
```

when You'll need to add new definition:

1. just add it to `database/definitions/User.js` as examples from other definition
2. and define it in `database/definitions/index.js` by adding a line:

```js
    module.exports.User = require('./User');
```

everything will be handled automatically.

3. and in Your example route:

```js
    app.get('/users/:id', async (req, res) => {
      try {
        const { User } = db.models;
        const user = await User.findOne(req.params);
        res.status(200).send(user);
      }
      catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send(error);
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! It's recognizing all of the models in the definitions constant now; however, I'm not sure what you mean by "// attach definition to sequelize connection" I tried:
    definition.sequelize.sync()

and got an error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'sync' of undefined

Comment: @KyleJosephGreen read carefully, I'm giving idea of separating files from DB driver. Attaching part is just iterating that definitions and attaching to Sequelize connection.

Comment: @KyleJosephGreen seems like I'll have to write for You that Sequelize to definition attaching logic)))

Comment: hmm... well I can see that each definition has a function for its value. Are you saying that I need to attach this function to the Sequelize Object?

Comment: @KyleJosephGreen I've wrote full realization of everything that You need with explanation how to extend with new definitions in future, the core concept is to return plain json definition and then attaching to sequelize connection. I hope You know basics of JS and NodeJS to understand what happens in `database/index.js`

Comment: Great write-up! That just helped me a lot. +1

Comment: @Christoph glad that was useful (:

Comment: thanks for this, but how does this work when the table is something like user_data but file in js is UserData naming convention?

Comment: @TannerSummers need to modify code and pass custom table name

Comment: @TannerSummers updated my answer to add table name support