# Why are all the Sequelize example models instantiated with Model(sequelize, Sequelize)?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Take a look at the models/blog.js definition in this [Sequelize tutorial](https://www.codementor.io/mirko0/how-to-use-sequelize-with-node-and-express-i24l67cuz).

```
module.exports = (sequelize, type) => {
    return sequelize.define('blog', {
        id: {
          type: type.INTEGER,
          primaryKey: true,
          autoIncrement: true
        },
        text: type.STRING
    })
}
```

It gets called like this:

```
const BlogModel = require('./models/blog');
const sequelize = new Sequelize('codementor', 'root', 'root', {...});
const Blog = BlogModel(sequelize, Sequelize);
```

I have scoured many more Sequelize example and found the *Model(sequelize, Sequelize)* "pattern" in probably at least 90% of them. Almost as if all of them derive directly or indirectly from some really poor code example, because...

This looks really ugly to me. There are two variables that are only distinguished by case. One of the is the Sequelize library, the other something like a session or connection (not sure which term Sequelize uses). Having upper-case variables is I think a coding guideline violation. Next, a library reference gets passed into another file, which should be completely unnecessary in Node because *requires* modules get cached on the first load. So why not just reference Sequelize in the model files directly and only pass the *sequelize* object?

Does someone see any good reason to do it this way? An IMO much cleaner way to do it is described in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50335123/node-sequelize-loading-all-models). Kudos to the answerer. I'm just wondering if I'm missing something obvious here, that I really *should* do it this way, or if I'm free to write some cleaner code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is really ugly. What I do is I create a db in it's own file and export it.

```
const db = new Sequelize(
  process.env.DATABASE_URL || `postgres://localhost:5432/${databaseName}`,
)

module.exports = db
```

In the blog.js file I'll import it and do something like this:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const db = require('../db')

const blog = db.define('blog', {
  your_field_name_here: {
    type: your_sequelize_type_here
  },
  ... and so on
})

module.exports = blog
```

Not entirely sure why they do it that way, but I find defining models this way much cleaner and it should achieve what you're trying to achieve. There are some out of date things the Sequelize docs, so it wouldn't surprise me if that's how things used to be.